# R failed to find 'stats' and 'utils' packages in M1 mac

Tags: r

When trying to open R (I tried to install and reinstall all available versions of aarn64 for the M1 chip) I get the following error message:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

tried to look for the .libPaths() and I can see the packages in the library.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your path in `.zprofile` is being altered? I had this issue today, with a non-system Python install modifying `.zprofile`. I commented out the `PATH` in `.zprofile`, sourced it, and then re-ran R without the errors.